# MeasureIt won't show actual size of my model, only when the Subdivision Surface modifier is applied

Tags: modifiers

Like the title says, when I am going to use MeasureIt, it says, thanks to the Subdivision Modifier, the correct size. Although, when I turn View Subdivisions to zero, it changes the size to one meter. Is there a way to somehow "apply" the subdivided size, without actually apply the entire modifier?
[image: https://jlcrag-bn1305.files.1drv.com/y4p6YQ2jrxnpKgw6Kv_iGKhi1wk9k3b_wMXc0LWGIkoOztmQhimvZDYv8PegbfYL0Dvc7vV822K_BCFt203lUhN2vdltjNQ31Jji26UtY4iF8tuRj_XotG9Gtl4DnblcwzwbknSoJG0QjXH8EPCkxcPjR_jd2vfrVCR1r0zEh0QmF7ZQQtyXNm4Muu4LYXJ3dKxHUyjl5dDs2rL0vYM-0m1Mg/MeasureIt%20Blender.jpg]

Comment: Could you include some screenshots of the object?

Comment: As you can see, the MeasureIt function does extend beyond the bulb of my ship. Thanks to the Subdivision Surface, that is set to one, not zero. The MeasureIt feature only seems to work with applied modifiers, especially the Subdivision Modifier.

Comment: Not as convenient as the addon, but could certainly be emulated by adding two empties to scene, snapping them to points, then using basic vector maths in py console.  Or make a copy of your object, apply mods and measure that.  Would either of these workarounds  suffice?

Comment: Oh yes! I didn't think of that! Thanks a lot! It works beautifully! You saved me a lot of headache!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted solution, provided by batFINGER. You add an empty to the scene, by either hovering over Add in the 3D View menu, selecting Empty -> Plain Axes, or, you can alternatively, hold <kbd>Shift+A</kbd>, and select Empty -> Plain Axes.

Then, a tip is to use the snap function (you find it in the 3D View menu as well, or, by simply pressing <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd>. Then select what you want to snap to. In my case, it was vertices. But you can snap to either vertices, edges, faces or even entire volumes. Or just incremental snapping.

You can choose what to snap to by pressing <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+Tab</kbd> to toggle between the different snap modes.

[image: Solution]